# Extract substr starting with TICKET# from string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to extract the ticket number from an email reply subject message. The subject message typically looks like this:

```
s = 'Re: Test something before TICKET#ABC123 hello world something after'
```

I would like to extract the part `TICKET#ABC123`

How can I achieve this the best in Python? Is this the way to go for my purpose or do you have better suggestions to keep track of mail chains?

Comment: have you tried by splitting and slicing ?

Comment: Not sure if that is the best, I need something that identifies from TICKET# up to end of that word. I tried split('#') but that returned a weird output.

Comment: This part 'TICKET#ABC123' meaning it will always have TICKET + # following 3 chars and 3 digits?

Comment: Not sure if it will be 3 chars and 3 digits, just know that it will start with TICKET# followed by something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without regex (using `split()` and `startswith()`):

```
s = 'Re: Test something before TICKET#ABC123 hello world something after'

splitted = s.split()

for x in splitted:
    if x.startswith('TICKET#'):
        print(x)

# TICKET#ABC123
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following *regex*:

```
import re
s = 'Re: Test something before TICKET#ABC123 hello world something after'

re.findall(r'TICKET#[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?=\s)', s)
# ['TICKET#ABC123']
```

**Explanation:**

- `r'TICKET#` - matches the characters r'TICKET# literally (case sensitive)
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]` - Match a single character present in [a-zA-Z0-9]
- `+` - Quantifier Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- `(?=\s)` - Positive Lookahead (?=\s)
- `\s`- matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])

Answer (score 1):

Using Regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re

s = 'Re: Test something before TICKET#ABC123 hello world something after'
m = re.search(r"TICKET#(\w+)", s)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

**Output:**

```
ABC123
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment on @Rakesh.

But we need to change the regex a little bit, since expected result is TICKET#ABC123

**Ex**:

```
import re

s = 'Re: Test something before TICKET#ABC123 hello world something after'
m = re.search(r"(TICKET#(\w+))", s)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

**Output**:

```
TICKET#ABC123
```

If you want to get the ticket number, then you can use

```html
m.group(2)
```